# request command equivalent to cURL command not working

Tags: node.js, curl, request

cURL command:

```
curl -F "json_query=</Users/somename/Desktop/API/payload/upload_image_payload.json" -F "file=@/Users/somename/Desktop/API/payload/image.png" http://url/api/upload_outgoing_media.php
```

node.js Command:

```
var options = { method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://url/api/upload_outgoing_media.php',
                headers: 
                { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' },
                formData: 
                { 
                    json_query: 
                        { value: 'fs.createReadStream("/Users/somename/Desktop/API/payload/upload_image_payload.json")',
                            options:
                            { filename: '/Users/somename/Desktop/API/payload/upload_image_payload.json',
                                contentType: null } }
                        },
                    file: 
                        { value: 'fs.createReadStream("/Users/somename/Desktop/API/payload/image.png")',
                            options:
                            { filename: '/Users/somename/Desktop/API/payload/image.png',
                                contentType: null } },

                };
                console.log("second")
                request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) throw new Error(error);

                console.log(response.body);
                });
```

Expected Output:
**{"meta":null,"payload":{"filename":"image.png"},"error":false}**

Returned Output:
**{"meta":null,"payload":null,"error":{"errortext":"no data","errorcode":null}}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

The

> "<"

in curl query is to load the contents of the json file and not the json file itself , so in NODE QUERY it must be :-

**json_query: jsonData** --> your json file data

```
formData: 
        { 
         json_query: jsonData,
          file:
          { value: 'fs.createReadStream("/Users/somename/Desktop/API/payload/image.png")',
           options:
           { filename: '/Users/somename/Desktop/API/payload/image.png',
            contentType: null } }

        }};
```

> **This worked and is returning the expected output.**